# Find Inflection Points & Slope of their Tangent Line

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1}$$

I can't figure this one out. I'm trying to find the inflection points and slope of their tangent line, how can I do this? Newbie to calculus.

Comment: Start by calculating $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$. What do you get?

Comment: Could people who approve edits please pay some attention??  Someone other than the poster added an answer, not as an answer below, but by editing the question.  I attempted to reject it, but someone else approved it while I was typing my reason.  _Then_ yet another person came along to improve the format in the added part.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Sorry, I suspected the person were the same as the OP, just with a different username, since it seemed like an answer to the question by Adriano.

Comment: Is there a way to tell whether it's the same person?  I think one should be very suspicious of such things.

Comment: o make the computation of the derivative more simple, you could rewrite $f(x)$ as $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{1+x^2-1}{1+x^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You can circumvent that by hitting "improve" and removing all the bad information.

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the tangent line at a point $x$ is the derivative $f'(x)$.

An inflection point is a point at which the second derivative $f''(x)$ is equal to $0$.

The derivative and second derivative can be found using the quotient rule of differentiation.